# How to assign custom action to dynamically created Active-X button?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up an Excel worksheet where I need to dynamically generate Active-X buttons and set up a different action for each one.

I get

> run time error 459 "Object or class does not support the class of events"

when I launch it.

I've seen similar questions but the solutions have been given for userforms.

My current solution.

I have a custom class module WoExp_FSelect_Btn:

```vb
Public WithEvents btn As OLEObject
Public id As Integer

Dim iCount As Long

' Action to handle button click
Private Sub btn_Click()
    '*** just for debug: show msgbox with id 
    MsgBox ("ID: " & id)    'Debug
End Sub
```

A collection is created with global scope to fit this kind of objects:

```
Public WoExp_DFileSel_Buttons As New Collection
```

Then I dynamically create the buttons running the following function inside a loop, i being the loop iteration:

```
Private Sub WoExp_AddFileSel_Btn(i As Integer)

    Dim cmdbtn As OLEObject
    Dim FselBtnWithEvents As WoExp_FSelect_Btn

    Set cmdbtn = Worksheets("Word Report Gen").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
            Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=75, _
            Height:=30)
    cmdbtn.Left = Worksheets("Word Report Gen").Cells(13 + i, 3).Left
    cmdbtn.Top = Worksheets("Word Report Gen").Cells(13 + i, 3).Top
    cmdbtn.Name = "WoExpDFileSel_Btn_" + CStr(i)

    Set FselBtnWithEvents = New WoExp_FSelect_Btn

    Set FselBtnWithEvents.btn = cmdbtn
    FselBtnWithEvents.id = i

    WoExp_DFileSel_Buttons.Add FselBtnWithEvents

End Sub
```

All buttons are properly shown if I comment the `Set FselBtnWithEvents.btn = cmdbtn` line, so I think that the problem is that OLEobject class and WithEvents don't go along.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the OLEObject object does not support the Click event.  If you go to your class module, select btn from the Object dropdown menu, and then click on the Procedure dropdown menu, you'll see that it only supports GotFocus and LostFocus.

However, when I replaced the Click event with either GotFocus or LostFocus, the same error occurred.  So maybe there's some sort of bug.